# Vscode keras intellisense(suggestion) not working properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Intellisense works fine on importing phrase

[image: image1]

But when it comes with chaining method, it shows different suggestions

[image: image2]

Python & Pylance extensions are installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [this issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1066#issuecomment-1022431087)
try adding this to the bottom of your `tensorflow/__init__.py` (in `.venv/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow` for me)

```
# Explicitly import lazy-loaded modules to support autocompletion.
# pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
if _typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
  from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v2 import estimator as estimator
  from keras.api._v2 import keras
  from keras.api._v2.keras import losses
  from keras.api._v2.keras import metrics
  from keras.api._v2.keras import optimizers
  from keras.api._v2.keras import initializers
# pylint: enable=g-import-not-at-top
```

The problem is because keras is a special class that enables lazy loading and not a normal module.

Edit: With updates to tf, vscode, or something else I'm not having this issue and don't need to use the above fix anymore. I just have to use `keras = tf.keras` instead of `from tensorflow import keras` and I have Intellisense working now.

Comment: thanks man I was looking for this from very long time.

Answer (score 0):

did you try clearing the cache on your system?

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

**Don't** import it directly like this

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
```

**Instead Do**

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras = tf.keras
```

After this change, Everything was fixed and started showing better suggestions including **function documentations**

Answer (score 0):

`tensorflow.python.keras` is for developers only and should not be used, but I think it is fine to be used as "type". I have also read it is a different version than the `tensorflow.keras` so have this in mind.

```
# Those are the imports, that actualy load the correct code
import tensorflow.keras as tfk
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers

# This is for typehinting and intllisense
import tensorflow.python.keras as _tfk
import tensorflow.python.keras.layers as _layers

# This gets highlighted as error by my linter, but it runs
tfk: _tfk
layers: _layers

# from now on, the intellisense and docstrings work
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

While `keras = tf.keras` does the trick, I was dumbstruck that IntelliSense on my home machine wasn't working. Turns out, the Jupyter notebook I was using wasn't using the right Python interpreter (conda environment with tf and keras both @ `2.11.0`) due to a window reload or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using conda with cuda and tensoflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

from tensorflow import keras

from keras.api._v2 import keras as KerasAPI


KerasAPI.applications.ResNet50()
```